# How to get linear or polynomial approximation of $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$?

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming

In mathematical program, one of the constraint has $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ term which can't be solved by the linear/quadratic solver.

Can someone please provide a way to represent this term as a linear or quadratic approximation?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! For which values of $x$?

Comment: In my formulation $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Why do you want such an approximation? If you have software reasons to do things with a linear or quadratic solver, why not approximate $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}$ instead?

Comment: I am using CPLEX linear solver. $x$ is decision variable in the constraint $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$, so it can't be used in the denominator. If I use Non-Linear solvers then it works but computation time is more. Therefore, I prefer to use linear approximation in CPLEX. Even if I get quadratic approximation that will be better so that I can switch to quadratic solver and save computation time as compared to Non Linear solver.

Comment: OK we understand that the solver is unsatisfactory. How could we help you if we don't know what equation the solver has to solve.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$$

[image]

Obviously a linear or quadratic approximation will be very bad. A main term $\frac{1}{x}$ is necessary.

We can use the series expansion of the function :
$$y(x)\simeq \frac{1}{x}+\frac12+\frac{1}{12}x-\frac{1}{720}x^3+\frac{1}{30240}x^5-\frac{1}{1209600}x^7+....$$
But there is no need for so many terms for the approximate on the limited range $0<x\leq1$.

Below, the comparison of results for different numbers of terms of the series :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response and all the error analysis. But there is one critical problem for $\frac{1}{x}$ term. Linear solver can't handle this division term. Can you please suggest some other way to approximate the term without $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: Replace $\frac{1}{x}$ by $\frac{1}{x+0.000001}$ or something like that..By the way, what a strange solver you got or what strange way you use it !!!

Comment: If you expect more convenient answers you should explain the problem in full details with the context, as well as what you have donne and what you observed in the disfunction of the solver. Such as the question is presently written might cause down-votes and possibly the closure.

Comment: Ok. I will explain in detail. I am using CPLEX linear solver. $x$ is decision variable in the constraint $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$, so it can't be used in the denominator. I can use this $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ term in Non-Linear solvers but computation time will be more. Therefore, I prefer to use linear approximation in CPLEX. Even if I get quadratic approximation that will be better. At least I can change to quadratic solver and save computation time as compared to Non Linear solver.

Comment: Also you could record a table of discret values of the function $y(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$. Then use the this data  with linear interpolation between the points.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see this approach.